# When will Trusty be available in old-releases?

Tags: 14.04

I have a bunch of legacy servers still running on 14.04 that are in the process of being migrated. Do we know when will the updates be available in old-releases so I can plan to update the sources beforehand ?

Comment: There is no set date for when repositories get moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, except it occurs **after** the release has gone EOL.  Ubuntu 17.04 disappeared within days of EOL, whilst Ubuntu 17.10 still hasn't moved. Traditionally LTS releases are a little slower, but there is no defined timeline for the move.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't Ubuntu moving its repositories to old-releases anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142106/why-isnt-ubuntu-moving-its-repositories-to-old-releases-anymore) The title there may be misleading, as they are still being moved. As for the release, that question mentioned 17.10, but [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142107/22949) includes specific information about 14.04 that I think answers your question as best as it can currently be answered.

Answer (score -1):

Trusty is now available on [`http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com).

[image]

Ubuntu 14.04 user now will have to switch to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` to be able install software, perform update etc— though they won't get any further Security/Bug-fix updates from Ubuntu.

Comment: What I meant was this : http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ . There is no trusty in there.

Comment: Also, those are old *point releases* of Trusty. The old-releases server also has downloads of old point releases of Xenial and Bionic, even though Xenial and Bionic are still fully supported. As the page says, *"The following releases are also available which have been superseded by later point releases (the current point release is available on [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) as usual)"*