# Why isn't Ubuntu moving its repositories to old-releases anymore?

Tags: software-sources, versions, release-management

Since 17.10 Ubuntu has its archives still in Ubuntu Archives instead of old-releases. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

17.04 (Zesty) and 17.10 (Artful) *have* been migrated from [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) to [old-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/).

16.04 (Xenial), 18.04 (Bionic), 19.10 (Eoan), 20.04 (Focal), and 20.10 (Groovy, currently in development) are on archive, but that’s normal, since they’re still supported or not yet released.

[14.04 (Trusty) reached “end of standard support” in April 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), but it benefits from extended security maintenance until April 2022, and will only be migrated then at the earliest; there’s no set calendar for such migrations, the only guarantee is that it happens *after* EOL, which for LTS releases is at the end of extended security maintenance.

See also [When will Trusty be available in old-releases?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1140154/412264)

Comment: I remember I saw artful couple of days back on Ubuntu Archives. Still thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Hey Stephen!!! The definition of "End of Life" has been changed in the recent year. Now, for LTS releases End of Life=(End of Public Support + End of extended security maintenance). 14.04 actually reached end of public support a.k.a. standard support in 2019. That means the repositories of 14.04 will still be in main archives until it reaches "*EOL*" in 2022. You can see the new terminologies reflected on [Releases - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: Considering this I posted a [meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18790/816190) about the terminology last year. You may also be interested in [recent chat messages on the Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54761383#54761383). Thanks. :)

Comment: Ah, that explains the upvotes! Thanks for the info @Kulfy, I’ve updated the answer.